# Are these incremements a valid/useful pattern when mapping between modulo (crt)

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic, chinese-remainder-theorem

I have been reading about the CRT and noticed the following pattern.
Let's say that we are mapping the number $N \pmod {21}$ to the corresponding congruences $\pmod 7$ and $\pmod 3$.
For convenience I tabulate this:

|  | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **0** | 0 | 15 | 9 | 3 | 18 | 12 | 6 |
| **1** | 7 | 1 | 16 | 10 | 4 | 19 | 13 |
| **2** | 14 | 8 | 2 | 17 | 11 | 5 | 20 |

This just means that e.g. $10 \equiv 10 \pmod{21}$ and $10 \equiv [3,1]\pmod{[7,3]}$
Now I noticed per row the columns increment by $15 \pmod {21}$ from left to right or by $6 \mod {21}$ from right to left.
I noticed that e.g. for the case of $35 = 7\cdot5$ the columns again increment by $15 \pmod {21}$ from left to right or $20 \pmod {21}$ from right to left.

|  | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **0** | 0 | 15 | 30 | 10 | 25 | 5 | 20 |
| **1** | 21 | 1 | 16 | 31 | 11 | 26 | 6 |
| **2** | 7 | 22 | 2 | 17 | 32 | 12 | 27 |
| **3** | 28 | 8 | 23 | 3 | 18 | 33 | 13 |
| **4** | 14 | 29 | 9 | 24 | 4 | 19 | 34 |

I was wondering if that is a real pattern, if there is a specific theorem related to it or if it something we could use to quickly map from $\pmod {21}$ to $\pmod 7$ and $\pmod 3$. Although I don't understand how the increments by $15$ appear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, as if you go over in a row ,you have to go up by a multiple of $3$ but you need that multiple of $3$ to be $1$ modulo $7$ to factor in the change of column. Similarly, to go down a column, you need it to be a multiple of $7$ that is $1$ modulo $3$ .